# USB pop-up window?

Tags: windows, popup, usb

I am wondering whether it is possible to display a message to the user when he connects a USB device. For example, I want to program the USB so that any PC that the device is connected to displays the pop-up window, saying `Please leave the usb on this place`.

Comment: Well, its because is the USB of one of the student groups that i belong to...do you know how to do do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is NOT possible;

You wrote: "  I want to **program the usb** so that **any** PC that the device is connected "

You'd rather program the PC not the USB

USB is a storage device only. Unfortunatelly you can't program all the PC's that USb might get into

The **ONLY way** this might be (yes it won't work in every case I guarantee) be tweaked is to have autorun.inf file in the USB pointing to a program on the USB that displays the message you want.
`[Autorun]

 Open=msg.exe`

Due to most modern operating systems have tons of blocking mechanism to stop autorun programs this message has very **slight chance** to appear

Answer (score 0):

You will need to first register for [device notification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363432%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Then, you can [implement a callback to detect when your USB device is inserted or removed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363215%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Within that callback you can do your messaging to the users based of your inspection of which device was inserted or removed.

Answer (score 0):

This is only possible if the computer already has a driver installed for this device that implements this behavior. If, as I suspect, the device is actually a standard USB storage device, this is not possible.